# how to get last modified date if you click on link?

Tags: html, href

I have 2 links here, on clicking any link I need to get last modified date&time beside it ..

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" id="1"/a>First
            </td>
            <td>
                <script>document.write(document.lastModified + "")</script>
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" id="2"/a>Second
            </td>
            <td width="200px">
                <script>document.write(document.lastModified + "")</script>
            </td>
    </tr>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please correct your DOM. So many unclosed <a> and <td>

Comment: hope now you are able to understand.

Comment: Invoke a function on click and get the attribute from `td`

Comment: @Sid can you give me an example?

Comment: @NithinPaul has given an answer below.

Comment: what if i use a for loop for the list and display seperate times for it?is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="ShowDate(1)" id="1" >First</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span id="firstDate"></span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" onclick="ShowDate(2)" id="2">Second</a>
    </td>
    <td width="200px">
        <span id="secondDate"></span>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <script>
    function ShowDate(location)
    {
        if(location == "1")
        {
            $("#firstDate").innerHtml = Date();
        }
        else if(location == "2")
        {
            $("#secondDate").innerHtml = Date();
        }
    }
  </script>
  </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: what if i use a for loop for the list and display seperate times for it?is it possible?